# Arduino mega flash memory

Tags: arduino

I have read this in arduino mega specifications:

> Flash  32k bytes (of which .5k is used for the bootloader)
>
> SRAM   2k bytes
>
> EEPROM 1k byte

I have extracted arduino's memory with this command:

```
avrdude -p m2560 -c stk500v2 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1441 -U flash:r:backup.bin:r
```

My backup.bin file should be a 32k file but this file is very big (128k)
Can anyone explain me why ?

Thanks

Comment: I have made a mistake in my question

Comment: And that mistake would be?

Comment: I have 256k, not 128k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program flash size of a Atmega2560 is 256kb.

See https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega2560

You write

> avrdude -p m2560 -c stk500v2 -P /dev/cu.usbmodem1441 -U flash:r:backup.bin:r

which `m2560` is for Atmega2560.

If you want a 32kB Atmega device you maybe mean this one:

https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega32

Which is in `m32` on the command line for avrdude.

Which comes from:

> m32 = ATMEGA32 [C:\WinAVR\bin\avrdude.conf:4985]

It makes me wonder that you only see 128kb file size for atmega256 as it should have the double of it!